# Como alterar a fonte no RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, richtextbox

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para editar a fonte e a cor de uma palavra do RichTextBox no C# E se possível como eu faço para numerar as linhas.

Answer (score 1):

Para abrires uma janela (Dialog) onde podes escolher a font, podes adicionar um componente/objeto do tipo FontDialog ao teu form. Supõe que o nome do objeto de tipo `FontDialog` chama-se `fontDialog1`, então podes fazer algo parecido:

```
/*Se esta condição é verdadeira, quer dizer que o usuario clicou OK (escolheu uma font).*/
if(fontDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    richTextBox1.Font = fontDialog1.Font;
}
```